# side-by-side figures in Sweave

Tags: r, latex, sweave

I use this code to make figures in `Sweave`

```
<<label=fig1plot, include=FALSE >>=
plot(cars)
@

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
<<label=fig1, fig=TRUE, echo=FALSE>>=
<<fig1plot>>
@
\end{center}
\caption{Some caption}
\label{fig:fig1plot}
\end{figure}


<<label=fig2plot, include=FALSE >>=
plot(table(rpois(100,5)), type = "h", col = "red", lwd=10, main="rpois(100,lambda=5)")
@

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
<<label=fig2, fig=TRUE, echo=FALSE>>=
<<fig2plot>>
@
\end{center}
\caption{Some caption}
\label{fig:fig2plot}
\end{figure}
```

Now I want to put these two figures side-by-side and have captions like Fig 1 (a) and Fig 1 (b). Any ideas, comments and guidelines are highly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [subcaption](ftp://ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.pdf) LaTeX package:

```
\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
     \centering\large A
     % plot 1
     \subcaption{A subfigure}\label{fig:1a}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
     \centering\large B
     % plot 2
     \subcaption{Another subfigure}\label{fig:1b}
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{A figure}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
```

See also this: [How can I have images that are side-by-side and have numbers attached to each one?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1242/how-can-i-have-images-that-are-side-by-side-and-have-numbers-attached-to-each-on)

Comment: After adding `\usepackage{subcaption}` to my sweave document preamble, even before adding any subfigures, I'm getting messages like "\caption will not be redefined since it's already redefined by a document class or package which is unknown to the caption package. The `subcaption' package does not work correctly." I guess something has changed since this answer was accepted…

Answer (score 3):

I use the subfig package for this.  See http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/subfig/.  Example code looks like this:

```
\begin{figure}      
  \centering        
    \subfloat[One.]{...}    
  \hspace{.25in}%       
    \subfloat[Two.]{...} \\ 
    \subfloat[Three.]{...}  
  \hspace{.25in}%       
    \subfloat[Four.]{...}   
  \caption{Simple Case.}    
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 3):

I use columns for this, it lets me keep the figures seperate but lay them out the way I want.

```
\begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
<<label=fig1plot, include=FALSE >>=
plot(cars)
@

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
<<label=fig1, fig=TRUE, echo=FALSE>>=
<<fig1plot>>
@
\end{center}
\caption{Some caption}
\label{fig:fig1plot}
\end{figure}
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}

<<label=fig2plot, include=FALSE >>=
plot(table(rpois(100,5)), type = "h", col = "red", lwd=10, main="rpois(100,lambda=5)")
@

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
<<label=fig2, fig=TRUE, echo=FALSE>>=
<<fig2plot>>
@
\end{center}
\caption{Some caption}
\label{fig:fig2plot}
\end{figure}
  \end{column}
\end{columns}
```

Comment: Is this available outside of beamer?

Answer (score 1):

I would put them together as one figure using `par(mfrow=c(1,2))`, with just one `\begin{figure}`, code chunk, and `\end{figure}`.  There would be one common legend running underneath, but that's common.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'd like to have separate figures.